# Selenium Proxy Scraper - Chrome to Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, proxy

Can anybody help me turn this Chrome/Chromedriver Selenium script into one compatible with Firefox/Geckodriver?
Or if anyone has some comparable script that they wouldn't mind sharing /\ :)
I've tried proxybroker as well, but it also gives me error I'll probably create a new posting for.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import chromedriver_autoinstaller # pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install() # To update your chromedriver automatically
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Get free proxies for rotating
def get_free_proxies(driver):
    driver.get('https://sslproxies.org')

    table = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')
    thead = table.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'thead').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'th')
    tbody = table.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')

    headers = []
    for th in thead:
        headers.append(th.text.strip())

    proxies = []
    for tr in tbody:
        proxy_data = {}
        tds = tr.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
        for i in range(len(headers)):
            proxy_data[headers[i]] = tds[i].text.strip()
        proxies.append(proxy_data)
    
    return proxies


free_proxies = get_free_proxies(driver)

print(free_proxies)
```